# EF Code First deployment gremlins

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

After using DB first for all previous projects, I'm now trying Code First.  I have edited the connection string in my `web.config` to use "user id=...;password=..."  and the magic happens beautifully; the DB schema is generated!  But:

1. The seed data that I lovingly created in my `Configuration` class is not being inserted. In my dev environment, when I run `update-database`, the seed data works fine.
2. The first time I try to create a new Db Context object to run a query, the web site crashes, and I see an error message in the app log that it's trying to connect to Sql using the App Pool identity.  My connection string does not use integrated security.  Why should this be?

Answer (score 0):

You could just [follow this link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/05/20/entity-framework-using-database-migration-to-seed-our-database/). Or, this works for me. Here is the connection string in my .config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="data source=dataSource;initial catalog=initialCatalog;user id=userName;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=AppName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Here is the initialization:

```
public class SchoolDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolDBContext context)
        {
            IList<Standard> defaultStandards = new List<Standard>();

            defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 1", Description = "First Standard" });
            defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 2", Description = "Second Standard" });
            defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 3", Description = "Third Standard" });

            foreach (Standard std in defaultStandards)
                context.Standards.Add(std);

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

And here is the context:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext()
        : base("SchoolDBConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SchoolContext>(new SchoolDBInitializer<SchoolContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a [good link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx) as well.

Comment: All very useful information for a beginner to EF, but doesn't address either of my two questions.

Comment: I can only address general questions with general answers. Where is the connection string? The seed data is not being inserted, well when? Why do you expect it to be inserted? What version of SQL Server? I need more detail.

Comment: I found the solution; see my answer.  Thanks for your answer, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

OK, part of this is a "D'oh!", and part not so much.

1. The seed data needs to be invoked explicitly, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18017840/7850).
2. The connection string... well, I did set the connection string, but someone had changed it back without me noticing.  Reset the connection string to use username and password, and all worked fine.